# How can I switch java verisons in intelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using the linux beta installation on my chrome-book, and I'm trying to set up a project to use the jdk version 1.8. I previously had a project set up that uses jdk 1.11, and now it seems that even though the current project is configured to use jdk 1.8 in project settings etc, the maven installation used by intellij is still configured to use jdk 1.11. When I run java -version and mvn -verison in the intelliJ terminal, java 11 turns up. I tried changing the maven settings as well, but whenever I try to mvn compile and install, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, but it must be the fact that maven thinks this is java 11, when it's java 8. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Also check JDK used for Maven importer and the JDK specified in the Runner tab: https://i.imgur.com/SbuV0a9.png.

Comment: those both point to jdk 1.8

Comment: FYI, Sun/Oracle eventually dropped the « 1.x » from version naming of Java. So we just say « Java 8 » and « Java 11 » now. For marketing purposes, this happened in Java 5. For technical purposes, [this happened in Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223).

Answer (score 2):

CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-S  / Project / Project SDK -  you can choose existing or  add configure another one

Comment: that's already configured to point to jdk 1.8.

Comment: you may also right click on maven pom in project view and resynch it with project.     also check project langiage level.     setting souruce level im pom also helps

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had downloaded jdk-8u271-linux-arm64.tar.gz instead of jdk-8u271-linux-x64.tar.gz, which is why the code wasn't recognized after installing the jdk. Apparently the two are designed for different CPU architectures, and arm is for mobile devices, and wasn't compatible with my chromebook.